# Jquerymobile lists thumbnails formatting

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I am using jquerymobile to create list with thumbnails. It looks like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <p>Long thumbnail which I want to be divided into 2 lines and not just simply cut with ... ending</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

If I look at it inside browser it all works great but when I load it into mobile (which has of course smaller screen) my thumbnail gets cut. So it is not looking like this Long thumbnail which ... . But I want to show whole thumbnail and divide it into two or more lines. Is there a way to do this?

I also have this code inside

:

```
<p class="ui-li-aside"> Date or some text</p>
```

it is showing date on the right side of

. Again, at web browser it looks great but at mobile it just simply cuts my  so it look like Headi.... So is there a way to put ui-li-aside on the bottom of li so it will be organized as this

```
HEADING 3
Thumbnail first line (probably divided into two lines)
Thumbnail Second line (if first line is not enough)
                                                       ul-li-aside(actual date)
```

Right now it looks like this (on my mobile):

```
HEADI....       ul-li-aside(actual date)
Thumbnail firs....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to include `style="white-space: normal;"` in the tags where you want to display the entire text.

So you would have:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3 style="white-space: normal;">Heading</h3>
        <p style="white-space: normal;">Long thumbnail which I want to be divided into 2 lines and not just simply cut with ... ending</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**PS:** To include `white-space: normal`, use the `style` attribute in tags, and not the `class`, because it may not work since the `class` is often overriden by jQuery Mobile.

Hope this helps. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I have tested it just with little difference. I havent used <p class="ui-li-aside"> but instead of it I have used <p style="text-align: right"> So right now my date thumbnail is located at the bottom right as I wished. Right now I just need to test if white-space: normal divides my <p> into multiple lines so it would fit screen.